# AngularJS - Target specific element inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

I´m using **ng-repeat** to iterate an array and create a table. In that table, I have a button to make a download. When I click the download button I want the link to disappear and make a loading spin appear. The problem is, the spin is showing up in all the rows and not in just the one i click.

Html -

```
  <tbody md-body>
    <tr md-row ng-repeat="">
      <td md-cell>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center"> 

          <md-progress-circular ng-if="isSubmit"></md-progress-circular>

          <a ng-if="!isSubmit" ng-click="download($index)">Download</a>

       </div> 
      </div>
     </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

JS -

```
$scope.download = function(index) {

    angular.forEach($scope.downloads, function (download) {

      // I can console log the index i click
      console.log(index)

    });
}
```

Comment: You might need to add an `isSubmit` property to each of the objects you are looping over. Or create an object whose key is the index and value is whether they are being submitted.

Comment: @FrankModica like a boolean in my api response ?

Comment: It doesn't have to be in the API itself. You can add that property afterward in JavaScript.

Comment: You can add a property like @FrankModica said. Then, you can use the `$` prefix in this property in order to AngularJs ignore it, since it  is just a view property.

Comment: Thanks people is working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `$index` on the ng-repeat and instead a boolean `isSubmit`, use the index to compare to array index.

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
  <td>
      <md-progress-circular ng-if="isLoadingIndex == $index"></md-progress-circular>
      <a ng-if="isLoadingIndex != $index" 
         ng-click="download($index)">Download</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**CTRL**

```
$scope.isLoadingIndex = null;
$scope.donwload = function($index) {
  $scope.isLoadingIndex = $index; 
  //Rest of your code...
}
```

Comment: What if multiple can load at the same time?

Comment: The question is not about that, but simply use an array, push the indexes, and compare if contains indexes.

Comment: @The.Bear. Thank you very much